# Best way to migrate database in Sqlite in .Net application

Tags: sqlite, entity-framework-6, c#-5.0

I am very new in SQlite DB.
I normalized few tables in my Sqlite DB. (By splitting it in separate tables)
I just want to know what is the best way to write **migration script**.(For migrating data to the new tables) ?

I think, PL/SQL is not supporting in Sqlite scripts.
Normal Ado.net we can do by using **system.data.sqlite**.
In my project I am using entity framework also.

So please suggest me the best way of migrating data in SQLITE.

Comment: Why would you need PL/SQL? Just copy the data into the new tables with INSERT/SELECT.

Comment: I need because, suppose i have a table A which had 4 columns, after normalization there is 3 columns in table A. and new table B has contains the deleted column of table A & Id with FK relationship with table A.
So now while migration I need to copy the data of old tables as well as new tables.. So how can I achieve it?

Comment: Again, why would that need PL/SQL? If you'd had a concrete example, it would be possible to answer with conrete SQL statements to do the conversion.

Comment: correct .. in that case PL/Sql not needed. So how can I proceed? procedural ADo.net or Entityframework?  In case of EF how it would be (Code or DB first.. Any example?)

Comment: You can use any mechanism that allows to execute SQL statements.